Example of a topological group abelian, non compact, where all characters are trivial.
Problem Give an example of a topological group abelian, non compact, where all characters are trivial.
Let $\phi: G \rightarrow S^{1}$, $S^{1}=\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$. If $\phi$ is  homomorphism and continuous then $\phi$ is character of $G$ and if $\phi(x)=1 \hspace{5pt} \forall x \in G$, $\phi$ is character trivial. Let $\hat{G}= \{ \text{all characters of } G\}$.
In text topological groups, we can see $\hat{\mathbb{R}}=\mathbb{R}, \hat{\mathbb{S^{1}}}= \mathbb{Z}$ and $\hat{\mathbb{Z}}=S^{1}.$
As we can see, $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{Z}$ are abelians, non compacts, however I need a topological group abelian, non compact, such that $\hat{G}=\{1_{G}\}$, $1_G$ denotes trivial character.
Do you know an example such that satifies what I need? $\mathbb{Q}$ could be work?

The Pontryagin duality theorem tells us that such a counterexample cannot be locally compact. Unfortunately, I do not know whether such an example exists.

Perhaps this MO-post is helpful, for the non-compact case (the example by Todd).

It seems it works, do you know books about those topics of algebraic topology?
